# SVM from Scratch in R

Tags: r, classification, svm

I am attempting to build a linear SVM from scratch in R using gradient descent. I am nearly there, but I am running into an issue. I know that my true outcome contains 50 of 1 class and 50 of the second class. However, after making the calculations, my code is resulting in 46 in one class and 54 in the other class. For comparison of results, I am using the package `e1071`.

I am not sure why this is happening and it may be an issue with one of my formulas or code. If anyone can assist me, that would be very helpful.

So, the cost function I am using is:

$$ \lambda\|w\|^{2}+\left[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \max \left(0,1-y_{i}\left(w^{T} x_{i}-b\right)\right)\right] $$

And the gradient with respect to the parameters are:

if $y_{i} \cdot f(x) \geq 1:$
$$\frac{d J_{i}}{d w_{k}}=2 \lambda w_{k}$$
$$\frac{d J_{i}}{d b}=0$$

else:
$$
\frac{d J_{i}}{d w_{k}}=2 \lambda w_{k}-y_{i} \cdot x_{i}
$$
$$
\frac{d J_{i}}{d b}=y_{i}
$$

Where:

$$ f(x) = (w^{T} x_{i}-b)$$

Lastly, my update rules are as follows:

$$ w = w - \alpha \cdot dw $$
$$ b = b - \alpha \cdot db $$

The code I am using to make the data set:

```
#removing one of the classes
df <- iris[iris$Species != "virginica", ]
#converting the outcome variable to 1 and -1
df$Species <- ifelse(df$Species == "setosa", 1, -1)
#selecting the outcome variable
y <- df$Species
#selecting the predictor variables
x <- df[, c("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length")]
```

The code for the SVM algorithm using gradient descent:

```
  #specifying the learning rate
  Learning_Rate <- 0.001
  #specifying the number of iterations
  num_iterations <- 5000
  #specifying lambda, the tuning parameter
  lambda <- 0.01
  
  #specifying the number of observations
  n <- length(y)
  #specifying the number of features
  n_feat <- ncol(x)
  #scaling the predictor space 
  X <- scale(x)
  #converting y to a matrix
  y <- as.matrix(y)
  #initializing the weights (w) and bias (b) to be 0
  w <- matrix(rep(0, ncol(X)), nrow = ncol(X))
  #initializing the bias (b)
  b <- 0 
  #converting the y variable into appropriate labels (-1 and 1)
  #y <- ifelse(y <= 0, -1, 1)
  
  for(j in 1:num_iterations){
  for(k in 1:n_feat){
  for(i in 1:n){
    if(y[i] * (w[k] * X[i, k] - b) >= 1){
      w[k] <- w[k] - (Learning_Rate * (2 * lambda * w[k]))
    } else{
        w[k] <- w[k] - (Learning_Rate * ((2 * lambda * w[k]) - (y[i] * X[i,k]))) 
        b <- b - (Learning_Rate * y[i])
    }
  }
  }
}
```

Then, the prediction function:

```
predSVM <- function(w, b, X){
  class <- sign((X %*% w) - b)
  return(class)
}
```

This ultimately results in 4 misclassifications with group -1 having 46 and group +1 having 54.

One last note (an update). When I change the update rule to

$$w = w + \alpha \cdot dw$$

In the event of a misclassification, rather than

$$w = w - \alpha \cdot dw$$

I get the correct answer after 5000 iterations. I am not sure if this is correct. Does the update rule change in the event of a misclassification?

```
else{
        w[k] <- w[k] + (Learning_Rate * ((2 * lambda * w[k]) - (y[i] * X[i,k]))) 
        b <- b - (Learning_Rate * y[i])
    }
```

Update:

I implemented the PEGASOS algorithm found in: [https://home.ttic.edu/~nati/Publications/PegasosMPB.pdf](https://home.ttic.edu/%7Enati/Publications/PegasosMPB.pdf). I also get the same result as my first attempt, with group -1 having 46 and group +1 having 54. This is from a published source and I believe I have implemented it correctly.

The code is below:

```
  #specifying the learning rate
  Learning_Rate <- 0.001
  #specifying the number of iterations
  num_iterations <- 5000
  #specifying lambda, the tuning parameter
  lambda <- 0.01
  
  #specifying the number of observations
  n <- length(y)
  #scaling the predictor space 
  X <- as.data.frame(scale(X))
  #adding a bias (intercept) term to the predictor matrix 
  X$Intercept <- 1
  #rearranging the predictor matrix so the bias comes first
  X <- as.matrix(X[, c(ncol(X), 1:(ncol(X)-1))])
  #specifying the number of features
  n_feat <- ncol(X)
  #converting y to a matrix
  y <- as.matrix(y)
  #initializing the weights (w) and bias (b) to be 0
  w <- matrix(rep(0, ncol(X)), nrow = ncol(X))
  #initializing the bias (b)
  #b <- 0 
  #converting the y variable into appropriate labels (-1 and 1)
  #y <- ifelse(y <= 0, -1, 1)
  
  for(j in 1:num_iterations){
  for(k in 1:n_feat){
  for(i in 1:n){
    if(y[i] * (w[k] * X[i, k] - b) < 1){
      w[k] <- (1 - Learning_Rate*lambda)*w[k] + (Learning_Rate*y[i])*X[i, k]
    } else{
      w[k] <- (1 - Learning_Rate*lambda)*w[k]
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Your cost function appears to be wrong. You seem to include all points, not just those violating the margin.

Comment: @IgorF. I just posted the wrong one from my LaTeX file. I just updated it. Thank you for noticing. However, the cost function, now being correct, doesn't solve my problem because the derivations are correct, as checked from multiple sources.

Comment: great work! would love to see the final answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your updating code is wrong, not as the same as your theoretical formula. Here is the one working:

```
svm_gradient<- function(x,y,Learning_Rate=0.01,num_iterations=10000,lambda=0.1){
  #specifying the number of observations
  n <- length(y)
  #scaling the predictor space 
  X <- as.data.frame(x)#X <- as.data.frame(scale(x))
  #adding a bias (intercept) term to the predictor matrix 
  X$Intercept <- 1
  #rearranging the predictor matrix so the bias comes first
  X <- as.matrix(X[, c(ncol(X), 1:(ncol(X)-1))])
  #specifying the number of features
  n_feat <- ncol(X)
  #converting the y variable into appropriate labels (-1 and 1)
  #y <- ifelse(y <= 0, -1, 1)
  #converting y to a matrix
  y <- as.matrix(y)
  #initializing the weights (w) and bias (b) to be 0
  w_ini <- matrix(rep(0, ncol(X)), nrow = ncol(X))
  w=w_ini
  
  for(j in 1:num_iterations){
    for(i in 1:n){
      if(y[i] * (t(w_ini) %*% X[i,]) < 1){
        w[1] <- w_ini[1] + (Learning_Rate*y[i])*X[i,1]
        w[-1] <- (1 - Learning_Rate*lambda)*w_ini[-1] + (Learning_Rate*y[i])*X[i,-1]
      } else{
        w[1]=w_ini[1]
        w[-1] <- (1 - Learning_Rate*lambda)*w_ini[-1]
      }
      w_ini=w
    }
  }
  return(w)  
}
```